# What happens when you deploy one firebase function and you have a common dependency?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Take the example below:

```
//index.ts
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { mathFunction } from './helpers'

export const functionOne =  = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

return mathFunction(data.a,data.b)
})

export const functionTwo =  = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

return mathFunction(data.a,data.b)
})


//helpers.ts
export const mathFunction =  = (a:number,b:number) => {
return a+b
})
```

What happens if I modify the "mathFunction" and then `firebase deploy --only functions:functionOne`? Does the functionTwo uses the new version of mathFuntion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each exported function runs in its own container(s), which are built/rebuilt when you deploy that function. So if you run `firebase deploy --only functions:functionOne`, only `functionOne` will run with the updated dependency. The container of `functionTwo` will be unmodified, and run with its old dependency version.